# code review: finding </body> tag reverse search on a non-null terminated char str

Tags: c

`src` is a non-null terminated char string whose length is `data_len`.
I want to start from the end of this array, and find the first occurrence of `html </body>` tag.
`find_pos` should hold the position of the `</body>` tag with `src`

Does the code below look correct to you?

```
char *strrcasestr_len(const char *hay, size_t haylen, const char *ndl,size_t ndllen)
{    
   char *ret = NULL;
   int i;
   for (i = haylen - ndllen; i >= 0; i--) {
       if (!strncasecmp(&hay[i], ndl, ndllen)) {
            break;
       }
   }
   if (i == -1)
       return ret;
   else
       return (char *)&hay[i];
}
```

Comment: Looks like Lisp.  Use strrchr().

Comment: Do you want an answer in C or C++? Tagging both is pointless.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: in general,

is it safe to use c functions such as strstr and strcasestr on char arrays that are not null separated? my guess is not...if the "string to be searched" i snot found...there will be a overrun?

Comment: @vsc: `strstr` or `strcasestr` are not safe, but `strcmp`, `strncasecmp`, `memcmp`, `memchr` are.

Comment: why is it been downgraded to -2?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, very very fast.

```
char const* find_body_closing_tag( char const* const src, size_t const data_len )
{
    static char table[256];
    static bool inited;
    if (!inited) {
         table['<'] = 1;
         table['/'] = 2;
         table['b'] = table['B'] = 3;
         table['o'] = table['O'] = 4;
         table['d'] = table['D'] = 5;
         table['y'] = table['Y'] = 6;
         table['>'] = 7;
         inited = true;
    }

    for( char const* p = src + data_len - 7; p >= src; p -= 7 ) {
        if (char offset = table[*p]) {
            if (0 == strnicmp(p - (offset-1), "</body>", 7)) return p - (offset-1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another very fast approach would be using SIMD to test 16 consecutive characters against `'>'` at once (and this is what `strrchr` or `memrchr` ought to be doing).

Comment: demonstration: http://ideone.com/0wGNL