# Can input iterators be used where forward iterators are expected?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

To my knowledge, the hierarchy of iterator categories goes like this:

```
Random access -> Bi-directional -> Forward -> Input
                                           -> Output
```

Correct?

I always thought there was a rule, that if an algorithm expects a particular type of iterator, you can provide iterators of categories up the chain, but not down.  So I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447819/how-to-look-for-an-ansi-string-in-a-binary-file/6447881#6447881), where ildjarn <strike>suggests</strike> suggested (then later corrected himself) using `std::ifstream` with `std::istream_iterator` and `std::search` to find data in a in a file.  I was about to comment that you can't do that, because `search` expects Forward iterators, and `istream_iterator` is an Input iterator.  But just to make sure, I tried this:

```
std::istringstream iss("Elephant hats for sale.");
std::istream_iterator<char> begin(iss), end;

std::string sub("hat");
auto i = std::search(begin, end, sub.begin(), sub.end());
```

I didn't expect it to compile, but it did.  However, the results seem to be useless because if I follow it with this:

```
while(i != end)
{
    std::cout << *i;
    ++i;
}
```

There is no output.  So, my question is this: Is my compiler in error for allowing my call to `search` using `istream_iterator`?  Or are there no rules preventing this sort of thing?

Comment: Since my obvious blunder ;-] I updated my answer with links to a wrapper (from Boost.Spirit) for input iterators that make them suitable for use as forward iterators.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Can input iterators be used where forward iterators are expected?

No.  The difference between an input iterator and a forward iterator is that an input iterator is a "single-pass" iterator but a forward iterator is a "multi-pass" iterator.

Once you advance an input iterator, you can no longer access the previous elements in the range.  If you make a copy of an input iterator, both iterators remain valid until you advance one of them; then the other ceases to be valid.

With a forward iterator, you can iterate over the sequence any number of times, you can have multiple usable copies of an iterator at once, you can use multiple iterators into the sequence at the same time, and you can dereference an iterator as many times as you'd like before advancing it again.

> So, my question is this: Is my compiler in error for allowing my call to search using `istream_iterator`?

There is no rule that the compiler must reject the code.

The rule is that you must be sure to pass the right type of iterator that is required by the function.  Sometimes if you pass the wrong type of iterator you get a compilation error.  Sometimes the program will compile but will not function correctly.  Sometimes things will appear to work correctly.  The results are undefined if you violate the requirements of calling the function.

---

Generic algorithms usually impose requirements on their type parameters by assuming that the type arguments provided actually meet the requirements.  So, for example, an algorithm that only works with random access iterators will "enforce" this requirement by performing some operation that only works with random access iterators (e.g. `it + 1`).  If the iterator doesn't support that operation (`operator+(iterator, int)` here), the code will fail to compile.

The problem is that there is no way to distinguish between input iterators and forward iterators this way:  you can increment and dereference both of them; the difference is in how many times you can perform each of those operations and the sequence in which you can perform those operations.  So, an algorithm like `std::search` will use `*it` and `++it`, which will "work" just fine for input iterators, at least insofar as the code will compile.

In theory, an algorithm could use the `std::iterator_traits` class template to determine whether an iterator is an input iterator or a forward iterator; I don't know whether that would be permitted by the C++ language standard.  If the library did that, you could get a compilation error for your code, which would be better.

Comment: So it's undefined behavior, I should have thought of that.  Thanks James.

Comment: "*I don't know whether that would be permitted by the C++ language standard.*" Why wouldn't it be? Isn't refusing to compile a valid manifestation of UB?

Comment: @ildjarn:  I don't know whether it is required that a type have the correct `iterator_category` typedef in order to meet the iterator concepts.  I would think that _would_ be required, but neither libstdc++ nor the VC++ implementation takes advantage of that, so I am not sure.

Comment: "*Once you dereference an input iterator you cannot dereference it again until you advance it (using `++`)*". C++11 [24.2.3] says (for InputIterators) "the expression `(void)*a,*a` is equivalent to `*a`" --- this seems to indicate multiple dereferences are allowed. I don't see any mention about your other comment, "*If you make a copy of an input iterator, both iterators are valid until you advance* or dereference *one of them...*" --- I don't see why this dereference could invalidate the other iterator.

Comment: @nknight:  It appears you are correct (and that statement in my answer is incorrect).  I will correct it this evening.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: @James: It looks like you forgot to make the correction identified by nknight?

Comment: @BenVoigt:  So I did.  Thanks for the reminder.  I've actually had this question in my bookmarks since August so that I'd remember to revise the answer... I just forgot about it :(