# How to implement a Forward Traversal Iterator for Windows registry enumeration

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, iterator, boost-iterators

I was able to use [Boost Iterator Facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html) to build a *custom* [**Single Pass Iterator**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#single-pass-iterators-lib-single-pass-iterators) to iterate (in a C++ way) through the values contained in a Windows registry key, wrapping the C API [`RegEnumValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724865(v=vs.85).aspx).

E.g.:

```
// For each value 'v' under the given registry key 'hKey':
for (const auto& v : RegistryValueIterator(hKey)) 
{
    ...
}
```

Basically, the iterator's `increment` method calls `RegEnumValue` increasing the `dwIndex` parameter (initially set to 0 in the iterator class constructor), and when `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` is returned, that is mapped to the *"end"* iterator.

I've used the `boost::single_pass_traversal_tag`:

```
class RegistryValueIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade< RegistryValueIterator,
                                     RegistryValueEntry,
                                     boost::single_pass_traversal_tag >
{
    ...
```

Boost.Filesystem's `directory_iterator`, which wraps [the `FindNextFile` API in the Windows implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx), is implemented as a *single-pass* iterator, too. And similarly, the [`std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/directory_iterator) is an *Input Iterator* as well (*not* a Forward Iterator).

So, would it be possible for registry enumeration to upgrade the iterator category to a [**Forward Traversal Iterator**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#forward-traversal-iterators-lib-forward-traversal-iterators)? What steps should I follow to achieve that goal?

In other words, would it be possible to implement a *multi-pass* traversal required by Forward Traversal Iterators using the Windows registry APIs like `RegEnumValue`? If so, how?

---

**P.S.** I've discussed registry *value* enumeration/iteration, but things are very similar for enumerating/iterating through registry *keys* as well, using the [`RegEnumKeyEx` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724862(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Have you tried specifying `forward_traversal_tag` instead of `single_pass_traversal_tag`?  Did it work or not? What happened? I don't see anything in Boost's documentation that requires a "Forward Traversal" iterator to support "multi-pass traversal", only "single-pass traversal". You need to provide details of what you have already attempted, or else this is likely to get closed as off-topic asking for people's opinions instead of addressing technical facts.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Changing a tag isn't sufficient: you have to implement proper semantics. For ForwardIt being multi-pass vs. InputIt being single-pass read [this interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6449296/1629821). Note also that with FwdIt (see 3rd § in that answer) there are more features than InIt, e.g. can have multiple usable copies of an iterator at once, etc. It's unclear to me how to make copies of iterators when using RegEnumValue. ...

Comment: ... I've already provided details of what I did in my question: it's precise and not off-topic at all. I also did a fair amount of research before posting. If you know technical facts to implement a FwdIt for registry enumeration then provide those.

Comment: You explained how you implemented a single-pass iterator, but not what you have attempted so far to implemented a forward-traversal iterator, or what research you have found that you do not understand how to implement.  You just asked if it is possible, but nothing beyond that. In any case, to make a copy of a Registry enumeration, you can duplicate an open Registry key handle using `DuplicateHandle()`, copy the current index to another variable, and then you can enumerate the two handles independently of each other.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for the additional interesting information. Sounds like this is a path I can investigate.